# Android Activities and Views

Tags: android, android-activity

When developing an Android app, is there a rule of thumb for when you should stop changing layouts and instead switch to a new activity?  What factors might influence the decision?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no hard and fast rules, but I've got a few personal ones:

I primarily think of how my users will use the back button.  In an optimal app, the natural use of "back" to go through Activities is what I aim for.  Each time a user might want to use back, that should be a new Activity.  Of course, rules are meant to broken and sometimes you'll need to override the back button yourself to control a more complex interface.

Also, you shouldn't be tempted to call `setContentView()` again.  If you are tempted to redo the entire layout of the page, maybe you should move to a new Activity instead.

I would also check out [this guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/activity_task_design.html).

Answer (score 2):

There should be a rule that says "don't setContentView() twice". As written in [Application Fundamentals](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html#appcomp):

> An activity presents a visual user
>   interface for one focused endeavor the
>   user can undertake

So modifying the purpose of a given Activity will actually make you life harder than saving you writing more code.